# VS Code Plugin to show visual indicator for interface implementation

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goland

In VS code is there a go plugin that indicates interface implementation just like the one we have in IntelliJ? I am not able to find anything like that and it's difficult to navigate from one implementation to the interface type.

[image]

Comment: search the marketplace, if you can't find it write it

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings and ensure Inlay Hints are enabled: [image]

If your IDE is not too old, you should see these options.
With these hints, you will see implementations (inheritors): [image]
You can also see parent interface(s) ("Usages" hint).